# Matlab NN tool vs Neuroph

Tags: java, matlab, neural-network

Does anyone know about the difference between Matlab's Neural Network Tool and Java's Neuroph Library?

Recently I implemented an algorithm on Matlab and Neuroph.
However, the accuracy for Neuroph is different (30 % less than Matlab)

I used the same training data for both cases.

Comment: Are you sure that the optimization parameters, are the same?

Comment: Yes, Optimization parameters are same..